# the derivative of $n^x, n\in\mathbb{R}$ using the definition of derivative

Tags: derivatives, algorithms

I know that the derivative of $n^x$ is $n^x\times\ln n$ so i tried to show that with the definition of derivative:$$f'\left(x\right)=\dfrac{df}{dx}\left[n^x\right]\text{ for }n\in\mathbb{R}\\{=\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\dfrac{f\left(x+h\right)-f\left(x\right)}{h}}{=\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{n^{x+h}-n^x}{h}}{=\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{n^x\left(n^h-1\right)}{h}}{=n^x\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{n^h-1}{h}}$$ now I can calculate the limit, lets:$$g\left(h\right)=\frac{n^h-1}{h}$$ $$g\left(0\right)=\frac{n^0-1}{0}=\frac{0}{0}$$$$\therefore g(0)=\frac{\dfrac{d}{dh}\left[n^h-1\right]}{\dfrac{d}{dh}\left[h\right]}=\frac{\dfrac{df\left(0\right)}{dh}\left[n^h\right]}{1}=\dfrac{df\left(0\right)}{dh}\left[n^h\right]$$
so in the end i get: $$\dfrac{df}{dx}\left[n^x\right]=n^x\dfrac{df\left(0\right)}{dx}\left[n^x\right]$$
so my question is how can i prove that $$\dfrac{df\left(0\right)}{dx}\left[n^x\right]=\ln n$$

## edit:

i got 2 answers that show that using the fact that $\lim_{z \rightarrow 0}\dfrac{e^z-1}{z}=1$, so how can i prove that using the other definitions of e, i know it is definition but how can i show that this e is equal to the e of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}$?

Comment: If you are using the definition of derivative, it is illogical to use L'Hôpital's rule.

Comment: @Miguel i proved the case of L'Hôpital's rule for $\frac{0}{0}$ so i dont see why not

Comment: Because if you can compute the derivative to apply L'Hôpital's rule, you already know the derivative, which was your question to begin with?

Comment: @Miguel why? i proved that in case if $\frac{g(x)}{f(x)}=\frac{0}{0}$ than $\frac{g(x)}{f(x)}=\frac{g'(x)}{f'(x)}$, where did i found the derivative of $n^x$ there? i only use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$n^h = \exp((h \log n))$;

$\dfrac{n^h-1}{h} = \dfrac{\exp(h(\log n))-1}{h};$

$z: = h\log n$.

Then:

$\lim_{h \rightarrow 0}\dfrac{\exp(h(\log n))-1}{h} =$

$\lim_{z \rightarrow 0}$ $\log n \dfrac{\exp(z) -1}{z} =$

$\log n ×1= \log n$.

Used: $\lim_{z \rightarrow 0} \dfrac{\exp(z)-1}{z} =1$.

Comment: but how can i show that $\lim_{z \rightarrow 0}\dfrac{e^z -1}{z}=1$?

Comment: Textbook:  Exponential series expansion, with remainder, then inequalities.Simpler, infinite series, exp(z) = 1 +z+z^2/2 +....., subtract 1, divide, take the limit, less stringent.Is ok?

Comment: yes, thank you very much

Comment: Anytime, welcome, hope it helps.The inequality is kind of standard, derivation can be found in textbooks, Peter

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you feel you can assume about the function ln(x) and the number e.

See the link below for an approach similar to yours:
http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/DiffExpLogFcns.aspx

Comment: But how did they proved that $\frac{e^h-1}{h}$ when h is a limit to 0 equal to 1?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a definition of the logarithm handy (or suitable properties taken for granted), you cannot obtain the stated result because the logarithm will not appear by magic from the computation.

Assume that the formula $n^x=e^{x \log n}$ is not allowed. Then to define the powers, you can work via rationals

$$n^{p/q}=\sqrt[q]{n^p}$$ and extend to the reals by continuity.

Using this apporach, you obtain

$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{n^h-1}h=\lim_{m\to\infty}m(\sqrt[m]n-1)$$

and you can take this as *a definition of the logarithm*.

$$\log n:=\lim_{m\to\infty}m(\sqrt[m]n-1).$$